# how to insert coordinate of province to postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, coordinates, postgis-2.0

i need insert to database this area sample:
[
          [
            [
              50.227886556627098,
              31.15709614260982
            ],
            [
              50.227886335531331,
              31.157096406770776
            ],
            [
              50.227468173402542,
              31.157506958998855
            ],
            [
              50.227886556627098,
              31.15709614260982
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              50.488453280451964,
              30.816523649043251
            ],
            [
              50.488472645714253,
              30.816523648897526
            ],
            [
              50.488460603560483,
              30.816523679582151
            ],
            [
              50.488453280451964,
              30.816523649043251
            ]
          ]
]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  I recommend that you **edit** your question to provide some details about what you tried prior to posting your question.

Comment: INSERT INTO xxx(the_geom)
VALUES(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-71.060316 48.432044)', 4326));
Noe replace Point with POLYGON and take your sample string and replace all [] with () then remove , with " " (space) then remove ( ) from coordinate pairs. you should have string like POLYGON((50.2 31.2, 52.2 31.2, ....)

Comment: have error in insert , that error :geometry has too many points , please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connected to my database **world_borders**, I did (the first and the last point must be equal):

```
CREATE TABLE geometries (name varchar, geom geometry);

INSERT INTO geometries VALUES
('Polygon', 'POLYGON((50.488453280451964 30.816523649043251, 50.227886556627098 31.15709614260982, 50.227886335531331 31.157096406770776, 50.227468173402542 31.157506958998855, 50.227886556627098 31.15709614260982, 50.488472645714253  30.816523648897526, 50.488460603560483 30.816523679582151, 50.488453280451964 30.816523649043251))');
```

Afterward, in QGIS, the polygon (at Iran) looks as:

[image]

and much more closer it looks as:

[image]